# PHP - uniqid("",true) versus uniqid("")+mt_rand()

Tags: php, mysql, security, salt

What are the key differences between these two approaches to generate sequential-but-somewhat-unique numbers?  I want to use such a number as a unique user ID inside a MySQL db, and also as a salt to salt a password.

My understanding is that for clustering and indexing reasons those IDs should be sequential (I realize that in some cases the random string will make two entries that occurred in the same microsecond non sequential, but hopefully this is negligible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(scratch this, wrong info, sorry)

So yes, as Gumbo pointed out, it's not a hash but indeed a microsecond resolution increasing timer value, optionally concatenated with a random number. So, the values are still not sequential, but at least steady.
The difference between the two approaches would then be very small.

This one still holds: If you need unique *sequential* numbers, and you use MySQL, use an auto increment field, they do just that.

Comment: `uniqid` does not do any hashing at all. And it will generate values that are unique.

Answer (score 5):

Without using more entropy, [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid) does basically the following (see [source of *uniqid.c*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/uniqid.c)):

```
$time = explode(' ', microtime(false));
return sprintf('%s%08x%05x', $prefix, $time[1], $time[0] * 1000000);
```

So it basically takes the current time in microseconds and turns them into a hexadecimal representation and appends it to the prefix. This does already provide unique values.

But the values are not quite random. For getting more random values, you should add more entropy by setting the second parameter *more_entropy*. In that case PHP’s internal [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) `php_combined_lcg` (see [source of *lgc.c*](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/lcg.c)) is used to generate a pseudo-random number that is attached at the end, adding circa 30 bits of additional entropy to make them more random.