# Entropy in CSRF Tokens and Nonces

Tags: php, security, zend-framework, hash, nonce

I am making a classified ads site with Zend Framework (for portfolio purposes, yes I know the world doesn't have room for "yet another Craigslist clone"). I am trying to implement the ability to post/edit/delete without ever needing an account.

To do this, I feel like I need to have a Nonce generated upon post submission and stored in the database. Then email a link to the user which makes a GET request for the delete, like this:

> http://www.somesite.com/post/delete/?id=123&nonce=2JDXS93JFKS8204HJTHSLDH230945HSLDF

Only the user has this unique key or nonce, and upon submission I check the database under the post's ID and ensure the nonce matches prior to deleting.

My issue is how secure the nonce actually is. If I use Zend Framework's `Zend_Form_Element_Hash`, it creates the hash like this:

```
protected function _generateHash()
{
    $this->_hash = md5(
        mt_rand(1,1000000) 
        .  $this->getSalt() 
        .  $this->getName() 
        .  mt_rand(1,1000000)
    );
    $this->setValue($this->_hash);
}
```

In reading about mt_rand(), [one commenter said](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#105587) "*This function has limited entrophy. So, if you want to create random string, it will produce only about 2 billion different strings, no matter the length of the string. This can be serous security issue if you are using such strings for session indentifiers, passwords etc.*"

Due to the lifetime of the nonce/token in the application, which could be days or weeks before user chooses to delete post, I think more than enough time would be given for a potential hack.

I realize `mt_rand()` is a huge upgrade from `rand()` as seen in [this visual](http://oi43.tinypic.com/vwtppl.jpg) mapping pixels with `rand` on the left, and `mt_rand` on the right. But is it enough? What makes "*2 billion different strings*" a security issue?

**And ultimately, how can I increase the entropy of a nonce/token/hash?**

Comment: just make sure to put a captcha on submits, otherwise your posts will be riddled with spam.

Comment: @dqhendricks Yeah, that's something I will be implementing, but should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such security it's not only important how long your output is. It counts how much randomness you've used to create it.

For `mt_rand()` the source of randomness is its seed and state (number of times you've used it since it was seeded). More `mt_rand()` calls will just give you more rehasing of the same randomness source (no new entropy).

`mt_rand()`'s seed is only 32-bit (anything less than 128bit makes cryptographers suspicious ;)

Strength of a keys with 32-bits of entropy is 4 billion divided by (roughly) number of keys you'll generate (e.g. after 100K uses there will be ~1:43000 chance to guess any valid key, which approaches practical brute-forcing).

You're adding salt to this, which makes it much stronger, because in addition to guessing the seed attacker would have to know the salt as well, so if the salt is long, then overall the key may be quite strong despite "low" entropy.

To increase entropy you need to add more random stuff (even slightly random is OK too, just gives less bits) from different sources than mt_rand: `microtime()`, amount of memory used, process ID... or just use `/dev/random`, which collects all entropy it can get.

*(edit: uniqid() has weak entropy, so it won't help here)*

Comment: With the algorithm he is using above, it becomes much more complicated than guessing the result of an mt_rand().

Comment: uniqid() simply generates the current timestamp in hexadecimal form, and with true, it uses the current timesstamp + microseconds in hexadecimal form. I imagine this would be far simpler to guess, especially if the post has a time attached.

Comment: @dqhendricks It does have the time attached to the post. Is there a way to use /dev/random with one of these functions?

Comment: @cillosis as I explained in my answer, the possible outcomes of Zend's hash generation is far FAR higher than mt_rand() alone. You are over complicating this.

Comment: @dqhendricks: thanks for the info on uniqid. In my answer I've noted that the salt makes it strong despite 32-bit entropy (although if the salt is short itself, then that still may be brute-forceable).

Comment: @dqhendricks [That statement about `uniqid` is not quite true.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5499218/53114)

Comment: @Gumbo I see, so the first part is a timestamp, but the more entropy adds a pseudo random number to the end. Good to know. strange that the function is faster *with* more entropy.

Answer (score 2):

The Zend hash generating code above's input for the md5() hashing function has 1,000,000 X 1,000,000 different possibilities. md5() has 32^16 (1208925819614629174706176) possible outcomes no matter what the input is. On average, the hacker would need to send 500,000,000,000 requests to your server in order to guess the right nonce.

At 100 requests per minute, that's about 3472222 days to hack.

Comment: That definitely sounds sufficient. In reality, we are talking about an application used to sell off people's junk...not high security banking. I'm just trying to up the security for practice and portfolio concerns.

Comment: @porneL since the rt_rand() result is hashed, there is no way to do what you are talking about.

Comment: @porneL also, I am aware that the number of possible outcomes of md5 is irrelevent, hence why they were not used in my calculations. if the number of possible outcomes was less than 1000000 X 1000000 however, then they would have become relevant, which is why they were included in my answer.

Comment: @dqhendricks: mt_rand calls are not independent, so multiplication here is not correct. If attacker can guess mt_rand's seed, he can compute result of *both* calls. Number of md5() combinations is a red herring here, since it doesn't add any entropy (it can have at most as many outputs as unique inputs it gets).

Comment: @dqhendricks these mt_rand calls will never give you 10^12 unique combinations. The seed is 32-bit, so you can get only as many combinations as the seed (I presume it's computed once per request, every request is re-seeded) — attacker with knowledge of the algorithm would only need to test keys derived from 2^32 seeds.

Comment: @porneL The range of integer values that can be stored in 32 bits is 0 through 4,294,967,295.

Comment: @dqhendricks I think your answer mistakenly assumes mt_rand function is random. It's imperfect PRNG, and this imperfection does have influence on the probability of guessing the output. It's still pretty hard, but not the exact number you suggest. IMHO it's 2^31 against a single hash if the attacker knows the salt and the algorithm. 2^32/number_of_keys if any key is useful for the attacker. 2^127 if attacker doesn't try to guess algorithm/salt.

Comment: @porneL you are wrong, because even if they had knowledge of the algorithm, they would not know the hash salt. why don't you try it and let me know how it turns out.

Comment: @porneL you might as well be saying, they could do it, as long as they already had access to everything on the server, and even then it would be difficult.

Comment: @dqhendricks I'm just referring to formula *you've* used. Number you have given makes sense only if attacker knows the algorithm and the salt. Otherwise it's not 5*10^11, but 2^127.

Comment: @porneL you're right, so the entropy for the hash is all that matters if they don't have the source code and the salt.

Comment: @porneL where did you get 2^127th? that's about 170,141,183,460,469,184,368,712,360,312,360,016,728 right?

Comment: @porneL Wow, you guys feel better now that you got that out of your system? Thanks for all the information btw, it really helps!

Comment: MD5 has 2^128 = 32^25.6 possible output values.